# Nightmare.js - addEventListener click function won't execute

Tags: javascript, electron, nightmare

I am trying to figure out how to make script **click on link and go to some page, and then execute some action**. Here is example that I am stuck with, that doesn't work.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

nightmare

.goto("https://www.google.com/")
.type("input", "nightmare.js")
.wait(3000)
.click("button[type=submit]")
.wait(2000)
.evaluate(function(){
  var title = document.querySelectorAll("h3 a");
  i = 0;

  if (title) {
    title[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
          alert("Success!");
        }, 5000);
    });
  }
})

.then(function(result){
    console.log("result", result);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
});
```

As you can see, it won't even go to next page.

But if I define click like this, it will go to next page, but I need it to execute some function on that another page too:

```
.evaluate(function(){
  var title = document.querySelectorAll("h3 a");
  i = 0;

  if (title) {
    title[i].click();
  }
})
```

So it confuses me, not sure why it won't work.

Comment: `addEventListener` adds an event listener, but doesn't actually click, because that would immediately trigger the event which would be very confusing. It seems that your issue is that the `then` after `evaluate` doesn't correctly wait until the page is loaded, right?

Comment: @artjom-b I think that is exactly what happens. Because I get "result null" in terminal. How to fix that?

Comment: You get a result of `null`, because you're never returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think the main problem is with how you are trying to click that link.  Right now, you do it outside the main flow of nightmare chained callbacks (the `.goto().type().wait()`... chain).  If you change up the flow to work with the chain, and use `.click()` again instead of `.evaluate()`, you can execute an action on that next page:

```
nightmare
.goto("https://www.google.com/")
.type("input", "nightmare.js")
.wait(3000)
.click("button[type=submit]")
.wait("h3[class=r]")
.click("h3[class=r] a")
.evaluate(function(){
  return document.querySelector("h1 a").innerHTML
})
.end()
.then(function(result){
    console.log("result", result);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
});
```

and this outputs the content with the link of the Nightmare page's `<h1></h1>` tag which is "Nightmare"

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I need it tow work inside .evaluate() . :D

Comment: On which page do you want the work inside evaluate() to happen?